# Creating the client for the Java/Spring RESTful service

Tags: java, ajax, spring, rest, curl

I have developed `Java/Spring RESTful` service that returns `JSON` on the `cURL` requests. For example, if I provide `cURL` request e.g,

```
curl -G http://localhost:8080/rest/wallets | json
```

I get the response of the request,

```
[
  {
    "name": "Puut",
    "address": "mv7eLe6vva4SJ96tZiczd1XPYiUxgUudAX"
  },
  {
    "name": "Rool",
    "address": "n4W2zC6WE98SAAnKEJoatvELnbiLeVFZFf"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ouup",
    "address": "mj5DZbgngdK2Wnz4Q7Gv2UGYRyGSYnuhG6"
  }
]
```

I have the code in the

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class WalletRestController {

    @Autowired
    private WalletService walletService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/wallets", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<WalletInfoWrapper>> getAllWalletInfo() {

        List<WalletInfo> walletInfos = walletService.getAllWallets();

        if (Objects.isNull(walletInfos)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<WalletInfoWrapper>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }

        List<WalletInfoWrapper> walletInfoWrappers = new ArrayList<>();

        // hiding the entity ids for the security purposes
        walletInfos.forEach(w -> walletInfoWrappers.add(new WalletInfoWrapper(w.getName(), w.getAddress())));

        return new ResponseEntity<List<WalletInfoWrapper>>(walletInfoWrappers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    // some code 

}
```

The project structure is provided,

[image]

I need to develop a client for the `RESTful` with `Ajax` requests. For example, the code provided, say, in the front-end, it creates a drop-down menu with the wallets info `(name+space+address)` like this,

```
|----------------------------------------|
|Puut  mv7eLe6vva4SJ96tZiczd1XPYiUxgUudAX|
|----------------------------------------|
|Rool  n4W2zC6WE98SAAnKEJoatvELnbiLeVFZFf|
|----------------------------------------|
|Ouup  mj5DZbgngdK2Wnz4Q7Gv2UGYRyGSYnuhG6|
|----------------------------------------|
```

I see an example in the [tutorial](http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/java/rest_service_client.aspx), however, I need to know after creating the HTML page, do I need to write a controller to call it or what? e.g

```
@Controller
public class MyClass{

      @RequestMapping(value = "/", method= RequestMethod.GET)
      public String showHome(){
            retrurn "home.html";
      }
}
```

Some sample code snippet with `Ajax` requests will help me to get started.  How to do that?

Comment: You can use jQuery get/post methods. Did you try this: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Comment: I updated the question. I get to use `Ajax` as per requirements

Comment: no controller is necessary - just as you can call from `curl` you can also call from `jquery.ajax`

Comment: I'm so confused. Can you write an answer with a code sample? Where should I put the landing page or how to access that after running the `tomcat`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code sample using ajax. It shows how to call your rest controller.port can by vary depending on your config.but usually tomcat uses 8080 port.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/rest/wallets',
    data: '',
    success: function (responseData) {

            console.log(JSON.stringify(responseData));
    },
    complete: function (textStatus) {

    },
    error: function (responseData)
    {
    }
});
```

@Artin As you asked in the comment for complete html example so I give you an idea. I don't have any information about your drop down.

**Update:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Rest Service Calling example</title>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
  
 function getData(){
  $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   /*If you need some basic authentication then you need to include it also. 
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is for CORS issue*/
   /*headers:{
    "Authorization": "Basic *********",
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
   },*/
   
   url: 'http://localhost:8080/rest/wallets',
   /*Since you don't send any data, so data will be empty*/
   data: '',
   success: function (responseData) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(responseData));
    $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(responseData))
   },
   complete: function (textStatus) {
    
   },
   error: function (responseData)
   {
   }
  });
 }
  </script>
  
  <style>

  </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Data From Server : </p>
    <div id="result" ></div>
 <input type="button" value="Get Data" onclick="getData()">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where should I put the landing page or how to access it after running the tomcat? Do I need a `Controller` to reach out the landing page?

Comment: You can put it in `home.jsp`.

Comment: Ok, Do I need a controller to call the `home.jsp` ?

Comment: Suppose you have a page named `home.jsp`. Here is a button to show data. To load this view [e.g `home.jsp`] you should write a controller. In my case I used `ModelAndView` to load the view from controller.

Comment: You can deploy this HTML code as a different app, this will allow you to better control over the deployment cycle of each application.

Comment: @RishikeshDarandale, Yes, you are right. So that the server and client are loosely coupled.

Comment: @RishikeshDarandale How to do that? I need an example or to see how to do that

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna how to access the data from the `Ajax GET` inside the `HTML`? Can you write an HTML page with a drop-down menu with this info? A complete example will provide better understanding

Comment: @Artin, For creating dropdown, you need to parse the response [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and convert it to json object using `JSON.parse(responseData)`. Then iterate over the json object and [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) them in your select node.

Comment: How do I access the response inside the HTML?

Comment: You can found the response in `success` event after successful call in ajax. [Details](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-ab&q=ajax+success+function)

Comment: @Artin, The is very vast. For demo/poc purpose, you can directly consider the plain `html` with jquery(As used by @Ataur Rahman Munna). This can be run by just launching the `html` page in browser. You can host this simple application on [github](https://pages.github.com/)/[gitlab](https://pages.gitlab.io/) pages for free. If you prefer `AWS`, then you can use `s3` static website hosting feature for deployment of this html page. At a broader level, you can think of [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) or [Angular4](https://angular.io/) JS frameworks to develop the client application.

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'wallets',
   data: 'myAnyParameterIfNeeded=parameterValue',
   success : function(response) {
                var results = JSON.parse(response);
                // here you can use for loop for iterating into *results*
                var rowOneName = JSON.stringify(results[0]['name']);
           }
   error : function(e){
               alert('HTTP error number=' + e.status);
           }
})
```